# Receiving sms through gprs shield on Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, gprs

I have been searching all over the net trying to find some example code to see how to listen for sms and read it. I am new to at commands so I am trying to see some examples. My intentions is to listen for sms and read to content. If the message contained the word: 'forward', I want it to run a certain function. I am using a seeedstudio GPRS v1.4 shield with my arduino uno.

I found a library but I am confused on the readSMS() function. The library is found here: https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Seeeduino_GPRS.

I have the current code:

```
GPRS gprsTest(8,7,9,9600,"1818XXXXXXXXX");//TX,RX,PWR,BaudRate,PhoneNumber

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  gprsTest.preInit();
  delay(1000);
  while(0 != gprsTest.init()) {
      delay(1000);
      Serial.print("init error\r\n");
  }  
}

void loop() {
  //nothing to do
  gprsTest.readSMS();
}
```

My problem is I am not sure of what to put in the parameters for the readSMS function.

According to the api the function takes a int, string, and another int.

```
int readSMS(int messageIndex, char *message, int length);
```

Any ideas? Not really any documentation on receiving sms

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with Seeed-studio (whose comments in header files are not maintained very well as well, to give you some help) but here is the basic idea:
The received text messages are stored on independent indexes on the selected message memory (SIM or phone which will be modem in your case). New messages usually take the smallest unused index (indexes starting from 1).

There are two methods to detect a new SMS
1) Modem sends a string on output port to indicate new SMS (like an interrupt)
2) You have to read the count of unread messages yourself (polling)

These methods require a knowledge of hardware dependent AT commands. If you want to understand/learn what's going on, give AT commands **CMGR** and **CMGF** a read

That said, the information you have explicitly asked for can be found in the function **readSMS** of **gprs.cpp**.
`messageIndex` is the index of selected memory where the message is stored.
`*message` is the buffer the message will be read into.
`length` is the length of bytes to be read.
The return status is always 0 (not a good strategy).

I would recommend distinguishing between read and unread messages using custom code. It depends upon your application

Comment: Thank you for you help, I will research more on AT commands and also thanks for answering my question.

Comment: @JonathanDicamillo You're wlcome - I'd appreciate a vote up if it was helpful ;)